# Extrac data from Email and update the database using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently in a middle of a project where I want to extract details of unread emails and extract several information like Subject, Email and update the mySQL database using  run method of `commandLineRunner` .

**Progress**

I successfully extracted all the relevant information from emails. But when I try to save data on the database, I get following exceptions.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailReceiver': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'taxRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repo.TaxRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Can you implement run() method of CommandLineRunner inside another method,and invoke him directly

Comment: Please show your Java configuration for Spring Boot

Comment: You need to annotate your repository interface with @Repository